# Thermal runaway protection

Tags: pid-controller, thermal, thermal-cutoff

I'm having an oven that is heating a specific element. I have cascaded P/PI loops.
I have two thermo elements as sensors.

I would like to know how would I implement a thermal runaway protection.

For example If I'm heating and I removed the second thermocouple, it will heat forever, how would I know If specific element is burnt or the wire is cut or the wire is not there at all.

FOLLOW UP:

```
IF (rInputPWM = 1 ) THEN
    timerPWMDetection(IN :=TRUE, PT:= T#1S);

    IF(timerPWMDetection.Q) THEN
        counter := counter + 1;

        IF(rPreviousTemp < rTemperature AND counter = 60) THEN
            bRelay := FALSE;   
         END_IF

        timerPWMDetection(IN:=FALSE);
    END_IF
ELSE
    timerPWMDetection(IN:= FALSE);
    counter := 0;
END_IF

rPreviousTemp := rTemperature;
```

Comment: Your code is rather short of comments. You should also include a comment at the top to say what language / compiler it is for. (One of the END_IFs is out of line too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Industrial controllers use "Loop Break Detection" for this purpose. The control strategy is fairly simple:

- If the controller output goes to 100% then start the loop break detection timer.
- If the temperature does not start to move in the expected direction - upwards in your case - for a preset time - e.g., 60 s - then alarm and disconnect power.

The loop control could break for several reasons:

- Sensor hanging in the air instead of in the load.
- Reverse connection of thermocouple (driving reading the wrong direction).
- Open circuit of relay or SSR or heater element.
- Short circuit of relay or SSR leading to continuous full power application.

To protect against the last item a second relay or master relay is de-energised to independently remove power from the circuit.

Comment: Hi Transistor, how would I detect a 100% output ?

Comment: I'm switching on/off a transistor using PWM. Also how would I detect that the temperature is not moving upwards ?

Comment: I'm using ramping as setpoint generator

Comment: is that correct idea for code implementation https://pastebin.com/YA9tK4xq

Comment: "100% output?" You monitor your PI or PWM output which you are in control of. "*How would I detect that the temperature is not moving upwards?*" Save a value, check it in a few seconds. If it hasn't changed by a degree ... Put your code into your question so that everyone can see it. That way the question may be useful to others even if the link goes dead. I'll look at it later.

Comment: I attached the code in the original post

Answer (score 0):

You can use a resettable or non-resettable thermal fuse to cut the supply to the heating element when it gets too hot.

You put the fuse in series with the heating element; the fuse open circuits when it reaches a preset temperature. A resettable fuse will short circuit when it drops to a preset lower temperature.

Sometimes I add a non-resettable thermal fuse to heating circuits as a last-resort if the rest of the system fails.